# Nested attributes form error message customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, nested-forms

I have the following model

```
class OrgPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :TypRole
    has_and_belongs_to_many :OrgContact
    has_one :OrgCredential, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :OrgCompany, foreign_key:"org_company_id"
    belongs_to :TypPosition, foreign_key:"typ_position_id"
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :OrgCredential
end

class OrgCredential < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :OrgPerson, foreign_key:"org_person_id"
    validates :user_name, presence: true
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
    before_create :create_remember_token
    has_secure_password
end
```

and the following strong parameters:

```
def person_params
  params.require(:org_person).permit(:first_name, :last_name, 
    org_credential_attributes: [:password, :password_confirmation])

end
```

and the following new.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for(@person) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
    <div class="col-md-12 ">
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First Name", :class => "form-control" %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Last Name", :class => "form-control" %>
      <%= f.fields_for :org_credentials do |oc|%>
            <%= oc.password_field :password, placeholder: "Password", :class => "form-control" %>
            <%= oc.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Password Confirmation", :class => "form-control" %>
      <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    </div>
```

In shared/error_messages

```
 <% if @person.errors.any? %>
     <div id="error_explanation" class="col-md-12">
       <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
         The form contains <%= pluralize(@person.errors.count, "error") %>.
       </div>
       <ul>
       <% @person.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
         <li>* <%= msg %></li>
       <% end %>
       </ul>
     </div>
 <% end %>
```

[image]

The problem as shown in the picture is that it says something like "Org credential password is too short" when I only want it to say "Password is too short." I'm quite new to rails and I feel like I have to iterate through the error hash to spit out "Password is too short," but i'm not quite certain if this is the only way to do it or if there is an easier way. I hope someone who may have ran into the same problem can enlighten me on how they solved it.

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to take a look at Rails i18n (this is part of Rails Guides)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Associations**

Firstly, you need to be aware that Rails requires [`snake_case`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for the association name definitions - and [`CamelCase`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) for the Class Names:

```
#app/models/org_person.rb
Class OrgPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :typ_roles
   has_and_belongs_to_many :org_contacts

   has_one :org_credential, dependent: :destroy
   belongs_to :org_company
   belongs_to :typ_position

   validates :first_name, presence: true
   validates :last_name, presence: true
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :org_credential
end
```

--

**Messages**

In regards to your error messages, and as `Rahul Singh` recommended, you need to consider that you can define [custom error messages for your validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message)

You can do that using the the following:

```
   validates :first_name, :last_name,
       presence: { message: "You Need To Enter A Name!" }
```

This will give you custom messages, however, there *is* a sticking point with Rails, in that it's difficult to get the attribute name to be customized.

If you wanted to show the messages only, you'll be best using something like this (live code):

```
<% @person.errors.each do |attr,msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add custom validation error message in your model.

```
class OrgCredential < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :OrgPerson, foreign_key:"org_person_id"
    validates :user_name, presence: true
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, message: "Password is too short"
    before_create :create_remember_token
    has_secure_password
end
```

read through here [Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for you answers.

I didn't know that Rails had a sticking point to it, thanks Rich.

I actually used Michal's response to point me to the right direction.
Seems like the only way to actually get rid of the attribute name is to 
actually customize every single error message in the en.yml file within configs/locales.

The following guide is a very useful link that helped me fix this problem:

http://adamhooper.com/eng/articles/5

If anyone is running into the same problems, please refer to adam hopper's article.

The rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization was of some help, but not as much as the first resource.

Cheers!

Comment: Did you have to change the code a bit?  I am getting `uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Errors (NameError)`